# some issues in my jquery validation registration form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate

My problem is when i press the button or type in my `last` and `first` name one of them dont have a jquery validation on it. And how do i make the three comboboxes have a 1 rule  jquery validation instead of three poping out?

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/12/

```
 $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            fname: {
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 15,
                required: true
            },
            lname: {
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 15,
                required: true
            },

            month: {
                required: true
            },
            day: {
                required: true
            },
            year: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/14/)**

---

- You need to group the elements.

  ```
  groups: {
      DateofBirth: "month day year"
  },
  ```

And in `errorPlacement:`  part, add this

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.attr("name") == "day" || element.attr("name") == "month" || element.attr("name") == "year") 
                error.insertAfter(".dateWrap");
            else 
                error.insertAfter(element);
            if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
```

---

- For `lname` issue, your input field in html for first name has `id="lname"`. So there were two `<input>` elements with the ID as `lname`.

---

***Reference :*** **[.validate() groups](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups)**.

Comment: about the fname and lname do you know how to fix that?